# Using macro to set column widths ignoring merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following, very simplistic macro to set the width of a column, based on the column number.

```
Sub aaa()

a = 2
lColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)

While a <= 396

    Cells(1, a).EntireColumn.Select

    If Cells(1, a).Interior.Color = lColor Then

        Selection.ColumnWidth = 0.67

    Else
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 0.25

    End If

    Cells(1, a).Select

    a = a + 1

Wend


End Sub
```

It works well when there are no merged cells in the column. However, when there is merged cells, it selects all the columns of the merged cells.

Is there any way to select just one column at a time, based on column numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work if you avoid "select", which is a good idea in general.

Also I would recommend using a For-Loop here, which means you probably have to adjust the Column-Count from 396 to 395.

```
For a = 1 To 395
    With Columns(a)
        If (a) Mod 7 = 0 Or (a) Mod 6 = 0 Then
            .ColumnWidth = 2
        Else
            .ColumnWidth = 0.25
        End If
    End With
Next a
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works very well, and very fast

Answer (score 2):

Just changed your code a small bit:

---

```
Sub aaa()
Dim a As Integer
a = 2
While a <= 396
    If (a - 1) Mod 7 = 0 Or (a - 1) Mod 6 = 0 Then
        Cells(1, a).ColumnWidth = 0.67
        Else
            Cells(1, a).ColumnWidth = 0.25
    End If
    a = a + 1
Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Works very well.